# Pointing path from url to directory in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

Currently I'm using this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !production/
RewriteRule (.*) /production/$1 [L]
```

so if i'm hit `mydomain.org` or `mydomain.org/*` it will pointing to `public_html/production` folder

But now i need exceptional rules to point `mydomain.org/api` to folder `public_html/api`.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for your reference...

try this in your localhost. make one project folder then create one .htaccess file in your root directory

write below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([0-9]+)? http://triviamaker.com [R=301,L]
```

now run this,
localhost/*your_Project_Folder_Name*/game/_any_number/ ... when you run this url you will automatically redirect to another url which is set in .access file

I hope you understand this  thank you